# Property 'listing' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

i have just started learning angular and i could not resolve this initialization error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El2EJ.png)
kindly help me resolve it.

Comment: Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to paste the code instead uploading its screenshot. Secondly, try initializing your array as empty array.

```
listing: Listing[] = [];
```

As you are assigning an array to it in the ngOnInit method.